# ESP32 with Rest Api in Cloud Firestore

Tags: c++, google-cloud-firestore, esp8266, esp32

I'm working with ESP32 with Cloud Firestore. I'm attempting to make a request to get the data from a certain collection and document.

I have been able to access a single collection but, I'm having problems accessing a subcollection.

This is my ESP32 code to get the collection data:

```
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

#define lamp 13

const char* ssid = "SSID";
const char* password = "Ok";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  pinMode(lamp, OUTPUT);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  delay(5000);
  
  Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
}

void loop() {
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED){
    
    HTTPClient http;
    
    http.begin("stuff.net/app/api/read/5j5UF0lFovW8g5QSXXymWYsz0QB2");
   
    int httpCode = http.GET();

    if (httpCode > 0){
      String payload = http.getString();          //ISSO É PARA GET REQUEST
      Serial.println(httpCode);
      Serial.println(payload);

      char json[500];
      payload.toCharArray(json, 500);
      StaticJsonDocument<1024> doc;
      deserializeJson(doc, json);

      String device0 = doc["device0"];
    }
    
    http.end();  
  }else{
    Serial.println("Erro com conexão, chekar conexão ao WiFi");
  }

  delay(1000);

}
```

This is how my Firestore looks:
[image]

I have attempted:

```
https://stuff.net/app/api/read/5j5UF0lFovW8g5QSXXymWYsz0QB2/buttons/button0
```

Won't work

Comment: What does "Won't work" mean, specifically? What output do you see from your program?

Comment: If I attempt to user buttons/button0 I get the following output: `404
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /api/read/5j5UF0lFovW8g5QSXXymWYsz0QB2/buttons/button0</pre>
</body>
</html>
`